# How to pass data from children to parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where i want to increment the parent value from the children.

parent comonent:

```
getInitialState :function(){
    return {counter:0}
},

render(){
    <CallChild value={this.state.counter}/>
```

Child Component:
       `render(){ this.props.counter++;}` 
Any suggestions? Is it even possible to do something like this .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create method(which will change parent state) in parent component and call it in child like this

```
var CallChild = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return <div>
      <h1>{ this.props.value }</h1>
      <button onClick={ this.props.onClick }>+</button>
    </div>
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { counter: 0 }
  },

  handleIncrement: function () {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  },

  render(){
    return <div>
      <CallChild onClick={ this.handleIncrement } value={this.state.counter} />
    </div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/34821/)